# Disable fields on checked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to disable 2 select fields in a fieldset on check of a checkbox. I've also tried methods like `getElementById` or `getElementsByTagName` or `.attr()` but it doesn't work..

I hope to add `disabled` to `fieldset` like this when on checked:

```
<fieldset id="test" disabled>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('frequency_remarks'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('duration_remarks'); ?>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

The checkbox:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label for="CommentFrequencyOk">
        <input type="hidden" name="data[Comment][frequency_ok]" id="CommentFrequencyOk_" value="0" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="data[Comment][frequency_ok]" class="checkbox" value="1" id="CommentFrequencyOk" /> Frequency
    </label>
</div>
```

The script:

```
$('#CommentFrequencyOk').checked(function () {
    $('#test').setAttribute('disabled');
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suggestions:

1. Use `on('change')` to bind event, `checked()` is not valid event
2. Use `prop` to set the `disabled` status
3. Used `checked` property of checkbox to change the status of `fieldset`
4. You cannot call Vanilla Javascript methods on jQuery objects, use jQuery methods. Ex. `attr()` instead of `setAttribute` on `$('#test')`

```js
$('#CommentFrequencyOk').on('change', function() {
  $('#test').prop('disabled', this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset id="test">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <input id="frequency_remarks" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <input id="duration_remarks" />
  </div>
</fieldset>

<div class="checkbox">
  <label for="CommentFrequencyOk">
    <input type="hidden" name="data[Comment][frequency_ok]" id="CommentFrequencyOk_" value="0" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="data[Comment][frequency_ok]" class="checkbox" value="1" id="CommentFrequencyOk" />Frequency
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: @kovogel Can you please explain the difference, advantages and disadvantages of both `change` and `click` events on checkbox

Comment: change only fires when the actual state  "checked" is changed.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it. Now you only have to insert your select field ids instead of test.

```
$('#CommentFrequencyOk').change(function() {
   $('#test').prop('disabled', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```